# Can't modify frozen String on Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, immutability

I am a bit confused with the frozen string and utilizing them with test cases.

I just added the following line at the top of my test cases :

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
```

And i have the following two test cases:

```
    test "Create upload invoice invalid invoice id" do
          post :upload, params = {invoices_data: [{invoice_id: 987654, unit_id: 1321}]}
          assert_response :not_found
        end
    
   test "Create upload invoice request to fortnox with non array request parameter" do
      request = {invoices_data: {invoice_id: "invoice.id", unit_id: 321}}

      post :upload_invoices, params = request
      assert_response :bad_request
    end
```

All of a sudden my second test failed with

```
RuntimeError: can't modify frozen String
```

at this line

```
 post :upload_invoices, params = request
```

however, if I change the string to some symbol for instance `:invoice_id` then it works just fine.

Can someone guide why about the following two things:

1. Why does sending a string value fails in this case reporting that I
   am trying to modify a String and which string value I am trying to
   modify?
2. Why does it fail on post request, if it has to fail then it
   should fail when creating the request i.e  `request = {invoices_data: {invoice_id: "invoice.id", unit_id: 321}}`
3. What i can do to send string value instead of Symbol in the hash?

Comment: Are you sure the test is failing there? I mean - the request never even hits your controller?

Comment: yes, it fails before hitting the controller.

Comment: Seems like some code withing `post` attempts to modify the string value in your params, i.e. `"invoice.id"` (which is now frozen)

Comment: Since you **are** using auto-freezing of string literals (which is basically a good idea), you need to `.dup` the string if you pass it to some method which wants to modify the string.  In your case, it would however make sense to find out, why this modification takes place. It doesn't look right to me.

Comment: try running your tests with the `-b` parameter, so it prints the full backtrace. Then you can navigate the backtrace to see which method is trying to change this string. Feel free to post the backtrace here so we can give a look too

Comment: Not a minutest user but shouldn't `post :upload, params = { ... }` be `post :upload, params: { ... }`? Seems odd to be doing an assignment in a method call like that.

Answer (score 2):

1a) Sending a string value fails in this case because your `upload_invoices` controller action attempts to modify the `invoice_id` parameter itself. (Or you're running an old version of Rails where the `#post` method itself attempts to modify the `invoice_id` parameter by converting it to UTF-8 encoding.)

1b) The string value you're trying to modify is `"invoice.id"`.

2 ) It fails on the post request and not the assignment to  the `request` variable because the assignment to the `request` variable is not where the attempted modification happens. The frozen string literal  is attempted to be modified by the call to `#post`. See answer 1a above.

3 ) You can send a non-frozen string value in the hash a few different ways. You could remove the `# frozen_string_literal: true` magic comment, but I feel you don't want to do that. Otherwise, the simplest thing to do is to send along a duplicate of the string with either `+'invoice.id'` or the less esoteric `'invoice.id'.dup`. Or you can create a non-literal string with something silly like `['invoice', 'id'].join('.')` or `:invoice.to_s`. No doubt there are other ways.

However, it seems EXTREMELY unlikely you want to pass a string here at all. The `invoice_id`  parameter is almost assuredly an integer, and passing a string to it makes little sense unless I guess you're trying to test that the controller action can handle that kind of erroneous input. If so, one of the string duplication techniques `+'string_literal'`/`'string_literal'.dup` would be your best option.

I would wager by the name of the test that you're actually trying to send along a real `invoice_id` which means you don't want to pass along a string, but instead an integer. Maybe the ID of an `Invoice` fixture you have setup?

And on another slightly unrelated note, you're not passing params to the `#post` method properly. It should be `params: ...` not `params = ...`.

Comment: Or `+'invoice.id'` – the unary [+](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#2B-40-method) works like `dup` but only if the receiver is actually frozen.

Comment: @Stefan, of course. I'll add that to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes in post it tries to modify 


```
if params.is_a?(String)
          return params.force_encoding("UTF-8").encode!
        elsif !params.is_a?(Hash)
          return params
        end
```

inside this file actionpack (2.3.18.34) lib/action_controller/request.rb:505:in `force_encoding'

Comment: @AbdulSamad if this error is actually from within Rails, you're running a (very) outdated version. Problems with frozen strings were fixed _years_ ago.

Comment: Yes unfortunately we are using very old version of rails